# godot при паузе события кнопки в коде не работает

Tags: godot

я хотел создать меню при паузе в godot когда я нажимаю ескейп(сцена меню и остановки одна) игра должна остановиться и открыться меню но когда открывается меню я не могу нажать на кнопки(событие в коде не совершается) я пробовал убрать паузу все работает но игрок может ходить нужна пауза код меню

```
    if get_tree().paused == false:
        get_tree().change_scene_to_file('res://scenes/street.tscn')
    else:
        get_tree().paused = false
        visible = false


func _on_button_3_button_up():
    get_tree().quit()
```

и код остановки

```
    if Input.is_action_just_released("esc"):
            get_parent().get_parent().get_node("CanvasLayer/menu").visible = true
            
            get_tree().paused = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у Вас пауза создана как отдельный объект, можно попробовать аргументу "Node" во вкладке "Process" установить "Always" в инспекторе объекта:

[image: Process в инспекторе Node]

Comment: спасибо чел я довольно долго ждал ответа always что бы во время паузы он тоже реагировал типо вообще ВСЕГДА?